# Pagination in tinymce editor

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE as an editor in my website developed in PHP. I have to integrate pagination in that editor so that when user enters very long content it should get displayed on multiple pages instead of single one. Something like pagination. Please assist me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing this directly in the editor would be a little bit complicated.
An more easy way would be to check, if the editor contains more text as a specific threshold defines. When this is the case, a new tinymce editor for the second page will be created and so on for the following pages.

Comment: Actually giving separate editor will force the user to write a fix number of characters in a single instance of editor. But I want the user to feel it like he's writing in a desktop application e.g. MS-Word, where he/she can write as much as he/she wants and pagination will help them to navigate within that content instead of scrolling.
Is there any other way or any other editor to achieve similar kind of functionality?

Comment: You've said its complicated. Is it complicated or not possible at all. If there is any way to achieve this, kindly suggest or give some idea of how could it be done.

Comment: Maybe this is something for you: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:pagebreak

Comment: Thanks Johni! I'll try to use this to solve the issue. May be it could help me upto some extent.

Comment: Johni, your answer may be helpful for others but it didn't solved my problem. I'm trying something better solution for this by myself. And, waiting for another response as well.
But, thanks for the answer which would surely be helpful to someone.